# Confidence intervals cross exponential regression when predictors scaled across zero but not when positive

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I'm running non-linear regression analyses in R using the nls() function, and I've noticed some strange behavior with a particular analysis. If the independent variables contain both positive and negative values (say -400 to 400), the upper and lower confidence intervals cross the exponential regression when the independent values become negative (creating sort of an hour glass shape of confidence intervals - see figure on left). I wasn't really sure what was going on, and then I noticed it only happened in other models when the independent values became negative. So I made the independent variables positive (by adding the lowest negative value to all values), and now the confidence intervals don't cross and they look normal.

Any idea why this is happening? And whether my solution is appropriate?[image: Image contains two analyses: the first (left) with the predictor having negative and positive values and the second (right) having only positive values. raw data and code are identical]

Comment: how did you obtain the CIs and plot? using predict or?

Comment: CI's were calculated from standard errors and verified using nlstools::confint2(fit). I plotted using Datagraph.